# Python 2 string operation on a list

Tags: python, string, list

List needs to be converted to  a string and perform a string operations,

Is there a effective way to convert both the operations into 1,

```
lista = ['col-1,','col-2,','col-3,']

stra = ' '.join(lista)

stra = stra.rstrip(',')
```

Comment: Why the `.rstrip()`? There are no commas in your `Lista` items..

Comment: stra=`'a b c'`, there's no `,`?

Comment: You've answered your own question. `stra = ' '.join(lista)` makes a string from a list. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `join` returns a string.. So, instead of storing it, you can chain one more method call...

```
stra = ' '.join(Lista).rstrip(',')
```

Or, better you can do this: -

```
stra = ' '.join(s.rstrip(',') for s in lista)
```

This will not print comma(,) in between your list items..

Answer (score 2):

How about `', '.join(['col-1', 'col-2', 'col-3'])`? Then you don't need `rstrip` at all.

Comment: But you cannot change the input data. Maybe he has to work with that.

Comment: Then again, maybe not. Perhaps he assumed `join` only works for single characters, and munged the data to add commas. Or maybe you're right and the data is provided in that form. We'll see :)

Comment: There is a comma after each col,['col-1,','col-2,'], the solution provided by @Rohit worked.

Answer (score 0):

All string methods return new strings.

```
stra = " ".join(s.rstrip(",") for s in lista)
```

or if you only wanted to trim the last comma, just `" ".join(lista).rstrip(",")`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `join()` method returns a string you can chain methods:

```
stra = ' '.join(lista).rstrip(',')  # prints col-1, col-2, col-3
```

Or, if you want to strip the commas before joining the strings (since you have the comma at the end of every string I'm assuming you want to):

```
stra = ' '.join(map(lambda s: s.rstrip(','), lista))  # prints col-1 col-2 col-3
```

or:

```
stra = ' '.join(s.rstrip(',') for s in lista)  # prints col-1 col-2 col-3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "convert both the operations into 1", but if you don't have any control over lista, and can rely on it being in the format specified, then just do

```
' '.join(lista)[:-1]
```

If you *do* have control over lista, then follow [nneonneo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713081/1015178) suggestion and get rid of the commas in the list.